# Python path regex optional match

Tags: python, regex

I have path strings like these two:

```
tree/bee.horse_2021/moose/loo.se
bee.horse_2021/moose/loo.se
bee.horse_2021/mo.ose/loo.se
```

The path can be arbitrarily long after `moose`. Sometimes the first part of the path such as `tree/` is missing, sometimes not. I want to capture `tree` in the first group if it exists and `bee.horse` in the second.

I came up with this regex, but it doesn't work:

```
path_regex = r'^(?:(.*)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).+$'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think it works, is this not the expected? `^(?:(.*)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).+$` https://regex101.com/r/BD2eiE/1 If you don't want to cross the first forward slash, you can use a negated character class `^(?:([^/]+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).+$`

Comment: I updated the description. The regex101 you posted works, but if I have a path component with a dot it doesn't

Comment: With the negated character class it would work then? `^(?:([^/\n]+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$`  https://regex101.com/r/igeaXN/1

Comment: sorry, doesn't work for `bee.horse_2021/mo.ose/loo.se`

Comment: In that case you could also exclude matching a dot `^(?:([^/\n.]+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$` See https://regex101.com/r/MYlT5C/1 Or restrict the possible characters for group 1 to match only word characters `^(?:(\w+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$` See https://regex101.com/r/DY66LV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the characters to be matched in the first capture group.

For example, you could match any character except `/` or `.` using a negated character class `[^/\n.]+`

```
^(?:([^/\n.]+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MYlT5C/1)

Or you can restrict the characters to match word characters `\w+` only

```
^(?:(\w+)/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DY66LV/1)

Note that in your pattern, the `.+` at the end matches as least a single character. If you want to make that part optional, you can change it to `.*`